# CSS grid layout: image width set to 100%. Images in the grid are different sizes and dont line up

Tags: css, height, width

I am trying to have all my images maintain the same ratio in the grid. The width is fine but the height is off. Can anyone help out?

```
 .projects {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0.7rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    
     img{
     width: 100%
     border: 3px #fff solid;
     }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QtKE.jpg)

Comment: As i see from image, they are maintaining aspect ratio.You need to adjust `projects` (fixed height) or to distort images

Comment: Thanks.  I added height and it seems to be working well.  I'm just getting a little bit of distortion when I drop the screen size below 500px.

Comment: You are welcome, if you attach problematic code maybe i can help you